# Add file reference into database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to add the image reference of my uploaded image into firestore database. My code is uploading the image into the firebase storage but not save the data into the database. I am getting the error:

*Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom je object (found in field Image)*

What is the correct way to do this?

Please see codes below:

```
console.log("Initialisation Successful!");
var db = firebase.firestore();
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('Images');



function addExercise(){
    var exerciseName = document.getElementById("ename").value;
    var exercisePart = document.getElementById("body_part").value;
    var exerciseLevel = document.getElementById("elevel").value;
    var file = document.getElementById("eimage").files[0];

    var thisRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
    thisRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
         console.log('done!' + thisRef );
      });



    db.collection("Exercises").add({
        Name: exerciseName,
        BodyPart: exercisePart,
        Level: exerciseLevel,
        Image: thisRef 

    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Data entered successfully!");
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.error("Error!", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to save the full path of the reference, with `thisRef.fullPath`, as this is a simple string and not a full object.

To later translate that to an object that you could read, you'd do something like:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child(fullPath)
```

This obviously assumes the bucket hasn't changed -- otherwise you'd need to store the bucket name as well.

See more details here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference.

Comment: Hi rosiemb, thank you so much for your help. Your solution worked.